# Is there an idiom that means it's possible and not impossible?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means it's possible and not impossible? I could only think of "within the realm of possibility", which is a mouthful, and I am wondering if there's any good idiom I might have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the very casual term *Doable* which is pronounced like my spell checker tells me, 'Do-able"

Comment: This answer would be improved by linking to a good online dictionary that defines this term.